Adding data labels to bar chart in AG-Chart
I am using the community version of AG-Charts and would like to add data labels to the bars in a bar chart.  I have the tooltip enabled and the count represented by each bar is visible there, but I would like the count to be visible at all times not just on hover in the tooltip.  Is there an option to display data labels on bar charts similar to the option for pie charts?  I have searched the AG-Chart site repeatedly and I cannot find any reference to this ability.
UPDATE: I have located the proper attributes but I am seeing what I think is a bug, but perhaps I am missing something.  Here is my series code
{type: "bar", xKey: "month", yKey: "resources", yName: "Resources", fill: "#5B9BD5",  label: {enabled: true, color: 'black', placement: 'outside', formatter: formatNumber,} }
This works, but if I change the placement to 'inside' which is supposed to be the other option, the labels do not appear.  To further make things odd, if it is a stacked bar chart, the inside option works properly.

{
    field: "change",
    cellRenderer: (params: any) => {
      const data = params.value;

      return (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            width: "100%",
          }}
        >
          {data.map((item: any, index: number) => {
            const barWidth = item.count;
            return (
              <div
                key={index}
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  marginBottom: "5px",
                }}
              >
                {/* First Div for Names */}
                <div
                  style={{
                    width: "30%",
                    textAlign: "left",
                    // marginRight: "10%",
                    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                    // background: "yellow",
                  }}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </div>
                {/* Second Div for Bar Graph and Count */}
                <div
                  style={{
                    width: "50%",
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "start",
                  }}
                >
                  <div
                    style={{
                      width: `${barWidth}%`,
                      height: "15px",
                      position: "relative",
                      marginRight: "10px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <div
                      style={{
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%",
                        background: "grey",
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                  {/* Count */}
                  <div
                    style={{
                      fontSize: "12px",
                      color: "black",
                      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                    }}
                  >
                    {item.count}%
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    },
  },

you can de this way by in enterprise version...
